# Dynamically scale and translate shape

Tags: objective-c, scale, cgaffinetransform, uibezierpath

I am drawing a series of UIBezierPath's, all of which have different sizes and locations.  I would like to scale each shape to a specific size and move it to a specific location on a `UIView`.  I am working with `CGAffineTransformation` right now.  It is quickly becoming messy, as the location and size do not work for all the shapes.

Is there any way I can scale a `UIBezierPath` to a specific size and translate (move) it to a specific location that will work for most shapes?  Maybe there is a way to set the size and location of a shape without having to use transformations that I am unaware of?  The shapes I am drawing are all very different in size, some with jagged edges.

This is what I am doing so far with my AffineTransformations.

```
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f,2.0f); 
[path applyTransform:scale];

CGAffineTransform move = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-10, -10);
[path applyTransform:move];
```

Where `path` is a `UIBezierPath`.

Is that correct?  The values I am using (-10, 2.0f) are just examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to solve this problem is to convert the path into a CAShapeLayer and set the position and size of the layer.  Very simple and elegant.  However, there are some bugs that you will have to resolve depending on the implementation.

```
myCAShapeLayer.path = myUIBezierPath.path;
myCAShapeLayer.position = CGRectMake(x, y);
```

CALayers are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is how to apply an affine transform to a bezier path. Sure you can, with this method:

```
- (void)applyTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform;
```

This is how is the structure defined:

```
struct CGAffineTransform {
   CGFloat a;
   CGFloat b;
   CGFloat c;
   CGFloat d;
   CGFloat tx;
   CGFloat ty;
};
typedef struct CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransform;
```

And the fields meaning:

> Fields
>   a
>   The entry at position [1,1] in the matrix.
>   b
>   The entry at position [1,2] in the matrix.
>   c
>   The entry at position [2,1] in the matrix.
>   d
>   The entry at position [2,2] in the matrix.
>   tx
>   The entry at position [3,1] in the matrix.
>   ty
>   The entry at position [3,2] in the matrix.

Reference:

[CGAffineTransform](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGAffineTransform)
[UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I mentioned in the original post that I am currently working with AffineTransformations and that they are not working out very well.  If you believe this is what I should be doing, can you please provide a better explanation as to how I should be applying the transformation?

Comment: Please note that you added the code after I answered your question. That code should be correct, then if it doesn't work you're doing something wrong in another part of code. Show the full code if there's still some unwanted behavior.

Comment: I did add the code after you answered the question, but I originally mentioned that I was using CGAffineTransformations.  Either way, I found a solution and will post it soon.